# Django/html issue with displaying/linking image

Tags: html, django

I'm making a site by using django. One of my models contains ImageField.
Files are saved in main_dir/media/images. I'd like to display specific images in templates but I can't achieve it. Instead of photo, I can see only default image icon which mean ( i guess ) that image is not found

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, related_name='photos')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images')
```

views

```
def gallery(request, pk):
    gallery_object = Gallery.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {'gallery':gallery_object}
    return render(request, 'Gallery/gallery.html', context)
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Gallery: {{ gallery.name }}</h1>

    {% for photo in gallery.photos.all %}
        <img src="{{photo.image.url}}">
        <a>{{photo.image.url}}</a> #it's here only to check if path is correct
    {% endfor %}



    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go back to home page</a>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

what should I change to display image correctly ?

Comment: Are you working on localhost? If not, are you using nginx or apache? I say this because you may not have declared the media folder in the site setting

Comment: i m working on localhost

Comment: Can you access to the images through the url or the admin panel of Django? (Just to be sure that the problem is not the path or the folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i found an issue. I forgot about adding
`urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

to my urls.py file.
lmao

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the .get to .filter with the same condition to get multiple objects
because get will return 1 object only and you cant do the for loop in the template

Comment: It has to return 1 object beacuse there is only 1 gallery with the specific id.

Comment: one gallery has multiple photos, not vice versa

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong. First of all, if you want to return multiple images then you have to use .filter() instead of .get() and if you are .get() instead of the filter then you don't have to loop over it as it is giving a single object. And the image is stored in **Photos** model and for that you will have to call that instead of gallery.

Here is how you can fix it:
**For single object:**
views function:
def gallery(request, pk):
gallery_object = Photos.objects.get(id=pk)

```
    context = {'photo': photo_object}
    return render(request, 'Gallery/gallery.html', context)
```

HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Gallery: {{ photo.name }}</h1>

    
        <img src="{{photo.image.url}}">
        <a>{{photo.image.url}}</a> #it's here only to check if path is correct
    



    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go back to home page</a>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

**For returning multiple objects:**

views function:

```
def gallery(request, pk):
    gallery_object = Photos.objects.filter(#your query)

    context = {'photos': photo_object}
    return render(request, 'Gallery/gallery.html', context)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    

    {% for photo in photos %}
        <h1>Gallery: {{ photo.name }}</h1>
        <img src="{{photo.image.url}}">
        <a>{{photo.image.url}}</a> #it's here only to check if path is correct
    {% endfor %}



    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go back to home page</a>
    
{% endblock content %}
```